# Looking for an ongoing (2015) sci-fi webcomic with colonies and non-western cultures

Tags: story-identification, magic, space, space-colonization

I'm trying to track down a webcomic that was ongoing as late as this year, but can't seem to reconstruct it from anything.

Highlights:

- Indian transgender astrophysicist protagonist with bioluminescent tattoos
- Space colonies
- Japanese (-influenced?) long-lived elf (-like?) culture, possibly antagonistic to the culture portrayed as mainstream in the story
- Sciency magic present in the world
- Human augmentation/implants normalized in society
- Vertical-long rectangular page frame (like printed comics)
- Color presentation

Early on in the story, the main protagonist is asked to relocate to a nearby moon(?) for intriguing research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it after an exhaustive search of browser history on an old machine. The comic is called [IOTHERA](http://iothera.com/?webcomic1=mastuda-lowell-heavy-industries), and is still being updated.

[image: Iothera logo]

Comment: Reading now :-)